# Assign Fancybox title depending on class ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Consider this markup :

```
<dl class="target">
<dt class="gallery-icon">
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="1_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="hello"/>
</a>
</dt>
<dd class="wp-description-2" style='display:none'>Image Caption #1</dd>

<dt class="gallery-icon">
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="hello"/>
</a>
</dt>
<dd class="wp-description-3" style='display:none'>Image Caption #2</dd>
</dl>
```

what i'm trying to get is a different title displayed for each fancybox image.
So far, I've come up with this code but with no success. I really don't know much javascript. I would be grateful if someone could help me to get it right. This is the jQuery code :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
    var num_id = $('.target dd').attr('class').match(/\d+/);
    this.title = $(".wp-description-"+num_id).text();
}
});
```

The JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/1520/

Thank you

Comment: just curious : why `Caption #1` has class `wp-description-2`?

Comment: You're right , no need for it it's just something I had implemented in the hope it would help me get what I wnated, but in the light of the code ilyass gave me, there's no need for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i edited your fiddle, i hope this will help you :

http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/1521/

```
beforeLoad: function() {

     var num_id = this.element.parents('dt').next('dd').text();
     this.title = num_id;
},
```

you should replace :

```
 afterShow: function() {
    $(".fancybox-title").wrapInner('<div />').show();

    $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
        $(".fancybox-title").show();
    }, function() {
        $(".fancybox-title").hide();
    });
},
```

by pure css

```
 .fancybox-title{
    display:none;
 }
 .fancybox-wrap:hover .fancybox-title{
    display:block;
 }
```

The final result on another fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/1522/

Comment: If I can abuse :) Now I'm trying to have two different descriptions in the same fancybox  title:  please see  http://jsfiddle.net/Mhr5A/13/  . I tried  with some array but I don't know how to format it properly.  Thank you